# Laravel5.7: Get sum() for current month using model returned in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to get the sum of a field 'time_spent' for the current month, so when it's the next month it will start over again. I currently have in my model:

```
 public function transactions()
{
    return Transaction::groupBy('created_at')
    ->selectRaw('sum(time_spent) as sum')
    ->pluck('sum');
}
```

Then in my blade view I am calling using:

```
$info->transactions()->sum()
```

This does return the sum of time_spent from the DB, but it doesn't care about the created_at, I am assuming its not using it, My column for created_at is timestamp()

Comment: What you need exactly? The `time_spent` of all transactions or only the time from some month?

Comment: All transactions for the current month, so if am I viewing my page right now, it will only give me the sum of all transactions for the month of nov, when its Dec. it will only show me the sum of Dec, etc.. in the table, I have some info and the column time_spent and a timestamp column of created_at .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the methods `whereMonth` and `whereYear` to filter the transactions by the current month and year. After that, you can use the database's `sum` method to sum all time_spent.

Your method should look like this:

```
public function transactions($year, $month)
{
    return Transaction::whereYear('created_at', $year)
        ->whereMonth('created_at', $month)
        ->sum('time_spent');
}
```

This will run a query similar to this (it depends on which database you're using):

```
SELECT SUM(transactions.time_spent) FROM transactions WHERE YEAR(transactions.created_at) = 2018 AND MONTH(transactions.created_at) = 11;
```

To get the current month, you should call the method like this:

```
$month = date('m');
$year = date('Y');

$transactions = $info->transactions($month, $year);
```

Answer (score 0):

`created_at` is a timestamp from year to the second (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss).
If you are trying to sum by some month, you need to identify the year and month to do this.
So, use this instead:

```
public function transactions($year, $month)
{
    return Transaction::selectRaw('sum(time_spent) as sum')
        ->where('YEAR(created_at)', '=', $year)
        ->where('MONTH(created_at)', '=', $month)
        ->pluck('sum');
}

$year = 2018; //change in application
$month = 11; //change in application
$info->transactions($year, $month)->sum();
```